# Font in "Geometric Invariant Theory" by Mumford

Tags: fonts

Does anyone know what is the font used in Mumford's **Geometric Invariant Theory**? If yes is it available as package in LaTeX?

PS: Look up the book in Google books. Note that the final chapters which were added later are typeset with CM fonts.

Comment: Link: http://books.google.com/books?id=dFlv3zn_2-gC&lpg=PP1&dq=mumford%20geometric%20invariant%20theory&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: It looks like Garamond. And it is available as a latex font. Check the Latex Font Catalogue.

Comment: The only common point between Garamond and Monotype Old Style Series 2 is that they're both "old style" fonts. If you look at them closely (e.g. the lowercase "a", "g", "e"), they're very different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The font is Monotype’s “Old Style Series 2” which was one of the main fonts used for mathematical publishing along with Monotype Modern 1 & 7, Imprint, Times and Baskerville (in the US, one could also add Monotype Modern 8 and Century Schoolbook). Here’s a showing of the alphabet in the *Monotype Mathematical Sorts List* booklet by Arthur Phillips (1956):

[image]

You’ll notice that the italic *f*  is different, but it was quite common at the time to substitute an *f*  without kerns to ease the setting process. As often, they also used a generic set of numbers (from Monotype Modern, probably) which does not match the font.

Here’s a close-up of some characters from Mumford’s book (page 34) which are typical of Old Style Series 2 and allows to identify it:

[image]

Monotype did a digitalisation of it as [Monotype Old Style](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/monotype-old-style-mt/), but there’s no LaTeX package for it and no companion math font.

Comment: Thank you very much Philippe! It is a shame that these were not ported to LaTeX.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work any more: the font is now located at http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/monotype-old-style-mt/

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) website?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use [identifont](http://www.identifont.com/).