# Ask for font in LaTex

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Can anyone show me how to get this font (both text and math formula) in LaTex.
[image]

Comment: The font you are looking for is this one by the way: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8768/font-in-geometric-invariant-theory-by-mumford/8984#8984

Comment: @HenriMenke – It looks very similar, but is not an exact match. don't think it's an exact match. A few characters are clearly differetn (numbers, the g, the italic *x*, the italic p, and a few more)

Comment: You can try https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ --- but this seems a quite old document, (look at the baseline), and I think that in those times they did manual adjustments to simplify the typeset process, so it will be difficult to find an exact match.

Comment: I known how to use myfonts.com/WhatTheFont. But i want to use and get it in Latex. Thanks anyway everyone.